# The best method to convert piano sound to music notes in real time

Tags: fft, signal-analysis, frequency-domain, sound, audio-processing

I was looking for a way to convert piano sounds to piano notes for my research. I discovered the conversion of piano sound to piano notes using FFT and piano note recognition using CQT. I am also a beginner in signal processing. Can someone suggest me a method for converting piano sounds into piano notes?